# How good SilverLight as a technology is?

Tags: silverlight

I am working on a proejct which involve selection of technology as the first criteria.
The client is interested in web technology and is not in favour of ASP.NET.
I want to understand how good Silverlight is in following terms:
·         Scalability
·         Cost
·         Security
·         Compliance
·         Performance
·         Flexibility
·         Capacity
·         Reliability
Any idea on this is appreciated? Please help me to understand how can I present this technology with keeping these aspects in mind?

Comment: Security. Heh. Compliance. Heh. A Jedi craves not these things.

:)

Comment: Why are they not in favour of ASP.NET?  How is Silverlight an alternative to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 10):

Well for a start:

- Scalability - Irrelevant, it's a client technology
- Cost - It's free
- Compliance - With what?
- Performance - Good enough
- Flexibility - As much as Flash
- Capacity - Irrelevant, it's a client technology
- Reliability - Irrelevant, it's a client technology

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is a client technology, think of it as an alternative to Javascript/Flash. If you're developing a web solution you'll probably have to deploy something on the server side.

Silverlight can integrate easily with ASP.NET but you can put any other server side technology behind it (e.g. PHP, Java) with more work e.g. implementing web services. Silverlight alone will probably be not sufficient to fulfill technology requirement for a web project unless the website is absolutely static.